# How to set namespace in imported module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I need to call main app function from function in imported module.

Since, imported has it's own namespace it prints a name error: "global name...blah, blah..is not defined."

main.py :

```
from imported import importedFunction

def mainFunction():
    print "MainFunction"

importedFunction()
```

imported.py :

```
def importedFunction():
    print "importedFunction"
    mainFunction()
```

Do I need importlib method? Please help me to fix.

Comment: Please provide the *actual* error code you are getting, and the stack trace if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the function there, but it's not necessarily the best solution:

imported.py:

```
def importedFunction():
    print "importedFunction"

    from main import mainFunction
    mainFunction()
```

You should import from `main` in your function, because unless it you will have a loop in your imports.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't understand what namespaces are exactly.

For instance, to use a namespace on an imported module you do this:

```
from imported import importedFunction as func
```

And then in the rest of your code you can *refer* to the imported function as simply `func`.

Additionally, in your code, you are trying to call `mainFunction` from a module that does not contain `mainFunction` as it is in your module, the fact that you are importing `importedFunction` does not let it access functions in your module, because it is still acting inside its own module.

Unless you imported `mainFunction` into the imported module, but then you would create an infinite loop.... and that is normally frowned upon.

So to answer you "I need to call main app function from function in imported module". That is not possible unless you import your module into the imported module...